# How to determine if a cd/dvd medium is writable

Tags: data-cd

Is there any way to determine whether an inserted CD/DVD medium is writable or not on Linux?

It seems that the good old `cdrecord` had an option called `-minfo`, which is missing in `wodim`.

Comment: Do not use wodim, as it is an unmaintained and buggy fork from cdrecord from May 2004. Yes, `cdrecord -minfo` is the right way to go, add `-v` to get more information.

Comment: I found out that HAL has the information I need. `hal-device` delivers something like `volume.disc.is_blank = false  (bool)`. However, HAL is deprecated and almost completely replaced by UDEV. I did an attribute walk using `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sr0)`, but it seems that udev doesn't have the necessary information. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: It would be nice if this software (yes, it seems that udev is derived from hal as there are similar bugs) whould be implemented to do things correctly, but I don't expect that a program that incorrectly handles state transitions from a CD-ROM drive will do this for you. Hald and udev both try to mount a CD-ROM after a not-ready/ready transition without checking the important state parts. This e.g. may cause the burn process to be interrupted. BTW: What  problem do you have with calling `cdrecord -minfo`? It is even plarform independent.

Comment: I know that it is platform independant. The problem with cdrecord is that it is simply not present on my SLES11SP2 installation, `/usr/bin/cdrecord` is a link to `/usr/bin/wodim`. And no, I cannot install it just like that because it is an operational system.

Comment: If I read correctly and you are talking about SuSE Linux, there of course is the original cdrecord available as a binary packet. SuSE did deprecate wodim in 2013 and uses the original software instead. Given that many people with Linux installations have problems with hostile distros, it may be a good idea to document sowmewhere how to get working original software.  Is this what you like?

Comment: I am talking about SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Service Pack 2. No, unfortunately, I cannot modify the OS by any means. I am not able to install any packages.

Comment: What is your problem; is it missing account permissions or the lack of the right package for your installation?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use [GNU xorriso](https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/).
You can get info about particular drive and loaded media with:

```
xorrecord dev=/dev/sr0 -atip -toc --grow_overwriteable_iso
```

Results from not blank media can include:

> ...
> Media current: CD-R
> Media product: 97m17s06f/79m59s74f , Moser Baer India Limited
> Media status : is written , is closed
> ...

and from blank media:

> ...
> Media current: CD-R
> Media product: 97m17s06f/79m59s74f , Moser Baer India Limited
> Media status : is blank
> ...

Answer (score 0):

You should start by telling us what you try to accomplish.

Nevertheless have a look at **blank=all -dummy** for wodim.

Comment: Well. I am trying to determine whether the inserted CD/DVD medium is writable or not, i.e. "is the inserted disk empty or not?".

Answer (score -2):

cdrecord -minfo is the right way to go.

The reports from above with a different program contain less information that you will get with cdrecord.

-minfo was added 10 years ago and I recommend not to use software that did not evolve during the past 10 years anymore. So please just use a recent cdrecord.

You may like to add -v to -minfo, you may get better information.

Comment: I am running OpenSuSE Tumbleweed and the option is not available! Version: `Wodim 1.1.11`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know these code names but Suse reintroduced the original cdrtools in 2013 after they made a license review and after they realized that wodim is a dead project with many unfixed bugs since 2007. If you are using a halfway recent Suse installation, it should be simple to upgrade to a recent cdrtools. The ability to install wodim will probably go way soon.

Comment: My OS is almost bleeding edge, thus wodim/cdrecord has to be a new version as well. But, the option `-minfo` is not available.

Comment: -minfo was added in early 2006, so you seem to have a really outdated version installed.